# AES encryption key and IV

Tags: c#, aes

I have a function that encrypts my key text input from the user using AES. and decrypts it on request. What is an ideal way to maintain the key and IV for AES encryption(As of now hard-coded in application). I save the encrypted data every time in database. On page load encrypted value is retrieved from database. This value is decrypted on a button click. Is there any best I could use key and IV in a better way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The IV can be saved (or *can* even be "exposed"/transmitted publicly); it is [no 'secret'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5797231/215042). The key should be kept private. So you could save/transmit your data like `<iv_here>;<encrypted_data_here>`.

See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Initialization_vector_.28IV.29):

> An initialization vector (IV) is a block of bits that is used by several modes to randomize the encryption and hence to produce distinct ciphertexts even if the same plaintext is encrypted multiple times, without the need for a slower re-keying process.
>
> An initialization vector has different security requirements than a key, so the IV usually does not need to be secret. However, in most cases, it is important that an initialization vector is never reused under the same key.

Comment: So i can basically hard code both IV and key in my application without any worry?

Comment: No; the IV (usually) needs to be different (random and unique!) for each encrypted block of data. You do not want to use the same IV for each block of data you encrypt.

Comment: But i do need that same IV when i want to decrypt at later point in time. So should i maintain it somehwere else?

Comment: As shown in my post: you can store the IV "along" with the encrypted data or in a separate field. Doesn't matter. You could read up on IV's [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector).