# Circular dependency avoidance with Session class

Tags: php, oop

The problem is in regard to two classes, namely `Session` and `Encryption`.

To secure session data a little more, I've extended the built-in `SessionHandler` and encrypt the serialized session data on write.

To improve the security of other various areas of the site, some data is encrypted. The system stores the `Encryption` class' initialization vector in a `$_SESSION` variable, which the `Session` class manages.

This is a very clear case of circular dependency. Options to avoid this that I've come up with all involve bypassing one or the other class and directly using the built-in tools.

But this creates other problems! Currently I'm using `RIJNDAEL_256` for all encryption, if this ever needed an update, the code would then have 2 places in need of the change (possibly more by the end).

How can a situation like this be avoided while maintaining the current functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution ended up being fairly straightforward. First, I changed the `Encryption` class' `$iv` to static. Since it turned out to be impossible to encrypt only part of the session data using `SessionHandler::write()` as [peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2007760/peter) suggested (`write()` is all or nothing), the session data itself is now encrypted using the `ECB` mode (all other encryption uses modes involving an iv).

On session start, the iv is pulled from the previous session data (or created if it does not exist / is expired) and applied to the static `$iv` property within the `Encryption` class. Therefore `Encryption` no longer relies on `Session` and the `$iv` property is available across all instances!

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in encrypting initialization vector, since it is not a key a doesn't need to be kept secret. This removes your circular dependency.
[[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796954/secret-vs-non-secret-initialization-vector) [[2]](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3499/why-cant-the-iv-be-predictable-when-its-said-it-doesnt-need-to-be-a-secret)

As for specifying current encryption algorithm I'm not sure where you have duplicity. Ideally you should have one place, in a method or project configuration where you specify the currently used algorithm and let the interested parties use this common value.

Comment: How would you encrypt only part of the session on write to file?

Comment: By using namespaces; so if you access $_SESSION directly (not using any framework), than have $_SESSION['encrypted'] and $_SESSION['plain'] or something like that. Then the Encryption would work only with part of the session.